# Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel View format

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am loading Laravel view and exporting as Excel using **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel** but my data showing as text but i need to make it as decimal, number. how can i do this. I have already read the documentation but there i cant find solution.

```
$fileName = 'Receipt Register : From '.date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_from)).' To '.date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date_to)).($itemDetails ? ' For Item '.$itemDetails->item_code : "");
Excel::create($fileName, function( $excel) use($date_from, $date_to, $request) {

    $excel->sheet('Receipt-Register', function($sheet) use($date_from, $date_to, $request) {
        $itemDetails = [];
        $itemFilterData = [];

        $result = Ledger::where('receive_quantity', '!=', NULL)
                        ->where('receive_quantity', ">", 0)
                        ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
                        ->orderBy('mrn_number',"ASC")
                        ->whereNotNull('mrn_number')
                        ->whereNotNull('mrn_id')
                        ->orderBy('id', "ASC")
                        ->with('department', 'item', 'itemGroup', 'mrn')
                        ->has('mrn', ">", 0);

        if($request->date_from) {
            $date_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date_from));
            $result = $result->whereDate('date', '>=', $date_from);
        }

        if($request->date_to) {
            $date_to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date_to));
            $result = $result->whereDate('date', '<=', $date_to);
        }
        if($request->item_id){
            $result = $result->where('item_id', '=', $request->item_id);
            $itemDetails = Item::find($request->item_id);
        }

        $results = $result->get();
        $sheet->loadView('export_view',[
                        'results' => $results, 
                        'date_from' => $date_from, 
                        'date_to' => $date_to, 
                        'itemFilterData' => $itemFilterData
                    ]);
    });
})->download('xlsx');
```

Comment: Can you add more description? which fields do you want to convert from text to decimals? if you can show examples and also how you want it to look like, that will be very helpful

Comment: @Ernest thanks for the reply. but almost forgot or manage somehow the problem. It's almost 2 years past.